How to config karma with puppeter in docker?
I need puppeter to test some specifics pdf cenarios and stuffs.
currently my karmaConfig is:
module.exports = function (config) {
      const process = require("process");
      process.env.CHROME_BIN = require("puppeteer").executablePath();
      config.set({
        basePath: "",
        frameworks: ["jasmine", "@angular-devkit/build-angular"],
        plugins: [
          require("karma-jasmine"),
          require("karma-chrome-launcher"),
          require("karma-jasmine-html-reporter"),
          require("karma-junit-reporter"),
          require("karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter"),
          require("@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma"),
        ],
        client: {
          clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
        },
        coverageIstanbulReporter: {
          dir: require("path").join(__dirname, "./coverage/aaweb"),
          reports: ["html", "lcovonly", "text-summary", "cobertura"],
          fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
        },
        reporters: ["progress", "kjhtml", "junit", "coverage-istanbul"],
        junitReporter: {
          outputDir: "./junit/aaweb",
        },
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        aautoWatch: true,
        browsers: ["Chrome", "ChromeHeadless"],
        singleRun: false,
        restartOnFileChange: true,
        browserDisconnectTolerance: 2,
        customLaunchers: {
          ChromeDebug: {
            base: "Chrome",
            flags: ["--remote-debugging-port=9333"],
            debug: true,
          },
          ChromeHeadlessCI: {
            base: "ChromeHeadless",
            flags: ["--no-sandbox"],
          },
          ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
            base: "ChromeHeadless",
            flags: ["--no-sandbox"],
          },
        },
      });
    };

dockerFile:
FROM node:alpine AS build-angular
    
    WORKDIR /app
    RUN npm cache clean --force
    COPY ./ /app/
    RUN npm install && npm run build
    RUN npm test
    
    FROM nginx:alpine
    
    COPY --from=build-angular /app/dist/aplicationame/browser /usr/share/nginx/html
    
    COPY /nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    
    EXPOSE 80
    
    ENV CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
    ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD='true'
    RUN apk update && apk install chromium
    
    CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

but keeps giving me the error when the tests are executed:
[![Launching browsers ChromeHeadless with concurrency unlimited
60.11 11 09 2024 02:32:06.719:INFO \[launcher\]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
60.14 11 09 2024 02:32:06.751:ERROR \[launcher\]: Cannot start ChromeHeadless
60.14   Can not find the binary /usr/bin/chromium-browser
60.14   Please set env variable CHROME_BIN

I`ve already tried to set the path hardcoded like:
process.env.CHROME_BIN = /usr/bin/chromium-browser;

didnt work as well, is there something i`m missing?
maybe this question is duplicated cause i already read like 10 or more posts with the same doubt, but so far none of them solved this issue for me, so if anyone can give me a clue.
Thanks.
UPDATE:
I manage to solve the first issue by adding the following to the dockerfile:
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache \
chromium \
udev \
ttf-freefont \
nss \
harfbuzz \
freetype \
&& rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
      
ENV PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium-browser

but now i having the problem telling that:
ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported
witch is strange because i already put in my karma.config the following sections:
 browsers: ["Chrome", "ChromeHeadless"],
singleRun: true,
restartOnFileChange: true,
browserDisconnectTolerance: 2,
customLaunchers: {
  ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
    base: "ChromeHeadless",
    flags: ["--no-sandbox"],
  },
},
browsers: ["ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox"],
singleRun: true,
  });

